# Get Site Path From URL

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, site

How can I programmatically extract the site path from a given URL?  The solution would have to be able to handle paths with multiple levels of sub sites.  The number of sub site levels is also not always the same.

Here are two sample urls/examples and what I would like to get from them.

This one is two sub sites deep from the root site collection:

```
http://siteCollection/subSite/subSite/library/file.docx.
http://intranet/corporate/finance/financeLibrary/file.docx
```

Output: `http://intranet/corporate/finance`

And one that is only one sub site deep:

```
http://siteCollection/subSite/library/file.docx.
http://intranet/corporate/sharedFileLibrary/file.docx
```

Output: `http://intranet/corporate`

Comment: Will the URLs always point to a document in the library?

Comment: Yes they will always be to a document held in a library.

Comment: Why  not simply twice from last on '/'

Comment: Why don't you simply sub-string from last twice on '/'

Comment: That would work yes - thanks.  I should have mentioned that some of the documents may also be inside document sets which would add another level to the URL.  Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

```
string fullUrl = "http://siteCollection/subsite/library/folder/document.docx"
string siteUrl = string.Empty;

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(fullUrl)) 
{
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    siteUrl = web.Url;
}
```

This will take the full url path to a document and return the path to it's site, in this case `http://siteCollection/subsite`